# Do I need to call setAttribute() for every change if I use Spring Session?

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, cluster-computing, terracotta

I am in the progress of migrate my spring mvc + hibernate based application to clustered environment (Tomcat clustering). I am researching on the possible solutions for the session replication / sharing. From the [Terracotta documentation](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/best-practices#manage-sessions-in-a-cluster)

> All clustered session implementations (including terracotta Sessions)
>   require a mutated session object be put back into the session after
>   it's mutated. If the call is missing, then the change isn't known to
>   the cluster, only to the local node. For example:

```
Session session = request.getSession();
 Map m  = session.getAttribute("foo");
 m.clear();
 session.setAttribute("foo", m); // Without this call, the clear() is not effective across the cluster.
```

**Just want to know if the same rule holds true for Spring Session?** I mean the [Spring Session Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/)

Anyone knows the reason behind this rule? Is it because only when that method is called, Spring Session or Terracotta Web Session serialize the attribute object? Without this call, they don't know the object has changed? i.e. they won't monitor the object for changes?

Do you know a clustering solution that don't have this rule?

Comment: Have you tried it with Spring Session, also your reasoning is a bit strange because it work like that in Terracotta apparently it works like that for everything else as well?!

Comment: But to answer your question for Spring Session you shouldn't need it, that writes the session to the repository after every request, as you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java#L121). The `commitSession` saves it to the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your help. No, I haven't tried Spring Session. My application was built 5 years ago and at that time I was not aware of Spring Session. I remember read somewhere that one of the session managers come with Tomcat doesn't require setAttribute after every update. Write session to the repository after every request sounds not ideal for me as it will have impact on performance if the session contains not trivial amount of data.

Comment: If that is a concern then you are already using the session to much and for the wrong things imho.